# Markdown comparison view shows much bigger diff than there actually was

Tags: bug, markdown, suggested-edits

[image: Screenshot of suggested edit in Markdown view]

<sub>Click image to enlarge.</sub>

Here, I deleted the last section, because all it was was a broken link. I also made minor edits to the first and second sections. However, the markdown diff shows me making minor edits to the first section, deleting the second, and completely rewriting the third. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, sorry about that - markdown's shite

Comment: I think this is more an issue with the `diff` tool than markdown itself...